# Loop through form columns in Oracle Apex, send email + write in db

Tags: forms, loops, apex

I work in Apex  22.2.1

I have an application where one team sends requirements to another team via apex forms

I have this script to send email and write in database table:
It fires once the user clicks "create"

```
DECLARE
l_email_body VARCHAR2(4000) := 'Neue Bestellung Jira' || chr(10) || chr(10);

-- check if a value is not null and append the corresponding line to the email body
procedure append_line(p_label varchar2, p_value varchar2) is
begin
if p_value is not null then
l_email_body := l_email_body || p_label || p_value || chr(10) || chr(10);
end if;
end;

BEGIN
-- append lines for non-null values
append_line('Kunde: ', :P10_KUNDE);
append_line('Bestell-ID: ', :P10_BESTELL_ID);
append_line('Informationsquelle: ', :P10_NOTCSV_INFOQUELLE);
append_line('Versand an: ', :P10_NOTCSV_VERSANDAN);
append_line('Versand an Entscheidungsbefugte Stelle: ', :P10_NOTCSV_VERSANDENT);
append_line('Inbetriebnahme sofort starten: ', :P10_NOTCSV_SOFORTINBT);
append_line('Entscheidungsbefugte Stelle: ', :P10_ENTSCHEIDUNGSBEFUGTE_STELLE);
append_line('Entscheidungsbef Stelle manuell: ', :P10_NOTCSV_ENTMANUELL);
append_line('Zentrale Supportstelle: ', :P10_ZENTRALE_SUPPORTSTELLE);
append_line('Zentr Supportstelle manuell: ', :P10_NOTCSV_SUPMANUELL);
append_line('technischer Ansprechpartner: ', :P10_TECHNISCHER_ANSPRECHPARTNER);
append_line('tech Ansprechpartner manuell: ', :P10_NOTCSV_TECMANUELL);
append_line('universelle Sicherheitsgruppe: ', :P10_NOTCSV_UNISICHER);
append_line('Vorlage: ', :P10_NOTCSV_VORLAGE);
append_line('Projektschlüssel: ', :P10_NOTCSV_PROJEKT_SCHLUESSEL);
append_line('Projektverantwortlicher: ', :P10_NOTCSV_PROJEKT_VERANTWORTLICHER);
append_line('Projektname: ', :P10_NOTCSV_PROJEKTNAME);
append_line('Besteller: ', :P10_NOTCSV_BESTELLER);
-- send email and insert into database as before
apex_mail.send(
p_to => 'nobody@lanonymous.de',
p_from => 'anoynmous@nobody.de',
p_body => l_email_body,
p_subj => 'Neue Bestellung Jira'
);

-- Insert the email subject and body into the database table
INSERT INTO email_log (id, email_subject, email_body, bestell_id)
VALUES (MY_TABLE_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'Jira', l_email_body, :P10_BESTELL_ID);

COMMIT;
END;
```

---

Is there a chance to make the body-creation generic, so i do not have to manually edit the script for each form, or just very minor edits like edit page number?

my form region has the static id 'anforderung'

is there a chance to loop through all form items, and if they are not null to write them in the email body in the form 'column heading' (NOT column name) 'column value' ?
Bonus would be to leave out all columns with 'file' included in the column name (not heading), because those are blob related columns, that are not necessary here.

Thanks a lot.

I tried several approaches suggested by chat GPT but all caused syntax errors like

```
DECLARE
    l_email_to VARCHAR2(4000) := 'user@example.com';
    l_email_subject VARCHAR2(4000) := 'New Request Submitted';
    l_email_body VARCHAR2(32767) := 'A new request has been submitted with the following details:' || CHR(10) || CHR(10);
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..apex_application.g_f02.COUNT LOOP
        l_email_body := l_email_body || apex_item.get_label(p_idx => 1, p_item_id => 'F02_'||i||'_01') || ': ' || apex_application.g_f02(i) || CHR(10);
    END LOOP;
```

---

or

```
DECLARE
    l_email_to VARCHAR2(4000) := 'user@example.com';
    l_email_subject VARCHAR2(4000) := 'New Request Submitted';
    l_email_body VARCHAR2(32767) := 'A new request has been submitted with the following details:' || CHR(10) || CHR(10);
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..apex_application.g_f02.COUNT LOOP
        l_email_body := l_email_body || apex_item.get_label(p_idx => 1, p_item_id => 'F02_'||i||'_01') || ': ' || apex_application.g_f02(i) || CHR(10);
    END LOOP;
```